# How to multiply a BigInteger value by a BigDecimal value?

Tags: java

I have one BigInteger value and one BigDecimal value that I would like to multiply together and end up as a BigDecimal result.

For example if I have

BigInteger #1: 95

BigDecimal #1: 0.25124

Multiplying these together would give: 23.8678

Here is what I have tried:

```
    long firstLong = 95;
    float firstFloat = 0.25124f;
    BigInteger b1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(firstLong).toBigInteger();
    BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(firstFloat);

    BigDecimal multipliedResult = b1.multiply(bd1);
    System.out.println(multipliedResult);
```

Expected Output: 23.8678

Current Output: "The method multiply(BigInteger) in the type BigInteger is not applicable for the arguments (BigDecimal)"

Comment: Yeah, and you also can not multiply a `BigInteger` with `15` or `"a"` or `new Thread()` - what's your point again? Have you checked the API?

Comment: You need to learn to read the javadoc. If you do it, you'll discover that you can only multiply a BigInteger with a BigInteger, or a BigDecimal with a BigDecimal. But also that BigDecimal allows creating a BigDecimal from a BigIntgeer, or transforming a BigDecimal to a BigInteger. By composing these features, you can thus do whatever you need to do. But you need to read the javadoc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just turn things around:

```
BigDecimal multipliedResult = bd1.multiply(new BigDecimal(b1))
```

You can't do `someBigInt.multiply(someBigDec)`, but `someBigDec.multiply(someBigDecCreatedFromBigInt)` works nicely!